# Combine Eloquent (Laravel 4.2) Results Into Multidimensional Array Based On A Value

Tags: php, arrays, loops, laravel, multidimensional-array

I have this array that is returned from Laravel 4.2 Query Builder I am trying to rearrange a bit. I can't seem to figure out how to get the result I am looking for.

```
    array (size=8)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[565]
      public 'id' => int 53
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 11
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-27' (length=10)
  1 => 
    object(stdClass)[563]
      public 'id' => int 55
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 11
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-29' (length=10)
  2 => 
    object(stdClass)[567]
      public 'id' => int 61
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 7
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-30' (length=10)
  3 => 
    object(stdClass)[561]
      public 'id' => int 63
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 6
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-30' (length=10)
  4 => 
    object(stdClass)[572]
      public 'id' => int 64
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 8
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-30' (length=10)
  5 => 
    object(stdClass)[580]
      public 'id' => int 65
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 9
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-30' (length=10)
  6 => 
    object(stdClass)[579]
      public 'id' => int 66
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 10
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-30' (length=10)
  7 => 
    object(stdClass)[578]
      public 'id' => int 57
      public 'vehicle_id' => int 11
      public 'date' => string '2015-10-31' (length=10)
```

Example of desired result:

```
array(
  '2015-10-27' => array(11),
  '2015-10-30' => array( 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ), 
  '2015-10-31' => array(11)
)
```

I have tried foreach loops nested in for loops etc.. been driving me nuts for a while now. Am I missing something simple here?

Comment: please show us (at least some) of what you tried, and explain how it failes/what the problem is with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$dates = [];

foreach($yourArray as $obj) {   
    $dates[$obj->date][] = $obj->vehicle_id;
}
```

Comment: Not really sure how I missed that. Thanks.